# Unable to delete Docker image tags from private docker registry

Tags: docker

Following commmand is the one which I use regularly to delete docker image tags from our private docker registry V2 .

/usr/local/bin/registry.pl  -r http://localhost:XXX --delete --num 20 -i sample-image.

I'm getting following error when try to delete few tagged images. I can see the list of existing image tags and there digests in registry. Why this strange behaviour.

Error:

deleting tag 1234

tag digest not found: 404

Answer (score -1):

I have Bounced the server and then attempted to delete the images. It worked for me.

Comment: If you have persistence volume then it will not possible to delete from docker registry.